# como cambio la etiqueta <symbol> por una imagen en svg

Tags: html5, svg

soy estudiandte de diseño web y tengo una duda con svg, en mi caso quiero sustituir un icono que usa la etiqueta path, por uno que use la biblioteca imagen para poder obviamente insertar una imagen 
este es un ejemplo de un fragmento de mi codigo:

```html
<symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-6" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
   <path d="M11.366 22.564l1.291-1.807-1.414-1.414-1.807 1.291c-0.335-0.187-0.694-0.337-1.071-0.444l-0.365-2.19h-2l-0.365 2.19c-0.377 0.107-0.736 0.256-1.071 0.444l-1.807-1.291-1.414 1.414 1.291 1.807c-0.187 0.335-0.337 0.694-0.443 1.071l-2.19 0.365v2l2.19 0.365c0.107 0.377 0.256 0.736 0.444 1.071l-1.291 1.807 1.414 1.414 1.807-1.291c0.335 0.187 0.694 0.337 1.071 0.444l0.365 2.19h2l0.365-2.19c0.377-0.107 0.736-0.256 1.071-0.444l1.807 1.291 1.414-1.414-1.291-1.807c0.187-0.335 0.337-0.694 0.444-1.071l2.19-0.365v-2l-2.19-0.365c-0.107-0.377-0.256-0.736-0.444-1.071zM7 27c-1.105 0-2-0.895-2-2s0.895-2 2-2 2 0.895 2 2-0.895 2-2 2zM32 12v-2l-2.106-0.383c-0.039-0.251-0.088-0.499-0.148-0.743l1.799-1.159-0.765-1.848-2.092 0.452c-0.132-0.216-0.273-0.426-0.422-0.629l1.219-1.761-1.414-1.414-1.761 1.219c-0.203-0.149-0.413-0.29-0.629-0.422l0.452-2.092-1.848-0.765-1.159 1.799c-0.244-0.059-0.492-0.109-0.743-0.148l-0.383-2.106h-2l-0.383 2.106c-0.251 0.039-0.499 0.088-0.743 0.148l-1.159-1.799-1.848 0.765 0.452 2.092c-0.216 0.132-0.426 0.273-0.629 0.422l-1.761-1.219-1.414 1.414 1.219 1.761c-0.149 0.203-0.29 0.413-0.422 0.629l-2.092-0.452-0.765 1.848 1.799 1.159c-0.059 0.244-0.109 0.492-0.148 0.743l-2.106 0.383v2l2.106 0.383c0.039 0.251 0.088 0.499 0.148 0.743l-1.799 1.159 0.765 1.848 2.092-0.452c0.132 0.216 0.273 0.426 0.422 0.629l-1.219 1.761 1.414 1.414 1.761-1.219c0.203 0.149 0.413 0.29 0.629 0.422l-0.452 2.092 1.848 0.765 1.159-1.799c0.244 0.059 0.492 0.109 0.743 0.148l0.383 2.106h2l0.383-2.106c0.251-0.039 0.499-0.088 0.743-0.148l1.159 1.799 1.848-0.765-0.452-2.092c0.216-0.132 0.426-0.273 0.629-0.422l1.761 1.219 1.414-1.414-1.219-1.761c0.149-0.203 0.29-0.413 0.422-0.629l2.092 0.452 0.765-1.848-1.799-1.159c0.059-0.244 0.109-0.492 0.148-0.743l2.106-0.383zM21 15.35c-2.402 0-4.35-1.948-4.35-4.35s1.948-4.35 4.35-4.35 4.35 1.948 4.35 4.35c0 2.402-1.948 4.35-4.35 4.35z" ></path>
</symbol>
```

quiero sustituir eso por una imagen png o jpg,
sin mas nada que acotar me despido

Comment: Tendras el codigo o ejemplo de lo que quieres modificar? Saludos.

Comment: <symbol class="icon icon-" id="icon-6" viewBox="0 0 40 40"><path d="M11.366 22.564l1.291-1.807-1.414-1.414-1.807 1.291c-0.335-0.187-0.694-0.337-1.071-0.444l-0.365-2.19h-2l-0.365 2.19c-0.377 0.107-0.736 0.256-0.743l2.106-0.383zM21 15.35c-2.402 0-4.35-1.948-4.35-4.35s1.948-4.35 4.35-4.35 4.35 1.948 4.35 4.35c0 2.402-1.948 4.35-4.35 4.35z" ></path></symbol> es algo asi tuve que borrar parametros por cuestion de carcateres

Comment: El código que tengas añádelo  la pregunta y dale formato con el icono {}

Comment: no entiendo, me sige diciendo que tengo caracteres de mas inclusi si los encierro en {}`s

Answer (score 0):

**Primero**: Una etiqueta `<symbol>` dentro de un SVG nunca se renderea. Es sólo una plantilla que declaras una vez y luego puedes reutilizarla con una etiqueta `<use>`. [De la documentación en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol):

> Note that a symbol element itself is not
>   rendered. Only instances of a symbol element (i.e., a reference to a
>   symbol by a  element) are rendered.

**Segundo**: Puedes usar la librería [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) para leer el contenido del svg y convertirlo a un canvas. Y ese canvas tiene la función [toDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) para generar un data-url que le asignarás a una imagen en su atributo src.

El elemento `<svg>` que necesitas convertir debe contener una etiqueta `<use>`. No sacas nada con convertir un elemento que sólo defina un `<symbol>`

```js
function convertir() {

var the_svg=document.getElementById('el_svg').outerHTML.trim();
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var container_img = document.getElementById('contenedor_img');
 
container_img.appendChild(canvas);

canvg(canvas, the_svg);
var la_img = document.createElement("img");

la_img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1,{ignoreDimensions:false});
container_img.removeChild(canvas);

container_img.appendChild(la_img); 

}
```

```css
#convertir {
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
#contenedor_svg,
#contenedor_img {
padding:3px;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width:170px;
height:150px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvg.github.io/canvg/rgbcolor.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvg.github.io/canvg/StackBlur.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvg.github.io/canvg/canvg.js"></script> 
  
<button id="convertir" onclick="convertir()">convertir en imagen</button>
<div id="contenedor_svg">
Yo contengo un svg
 
<svg id="el_svg" style="height:100px;width:100px">
  <symbol id="sym01">
    <path d="M98.5,47.5C96.5,45.5,81,35,62,35c-2.1,0-4.2,0.1-6.2,0.3L39,26c0,4.5,1.3,9,2.4,12.1C31.7,40.7,23.3,44,16,44L0,34
 c0,8,4,16,4,16s-4,8-4,16l16-10c7.3,0,15.7,3.3,25.4,5.9C40.3,65,39,69.5,39,74l16.8-9.3c2,0.2,4.1,0.3,6.2,0.3
 c19,0,34.5-10.5,36.5-12.5S100.5,49.5,98.5,47.5z M85.5,50c-1.4,0-2.5-1.1-2.5-2.5s1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5s2.5,1.1,2.5,2.5
 C88,48.9,86.9,50,85.5,50z"/>  
  </symbol>
<use href="#sym01"
     x="0" y="0" width="100" height="80"/>
</svg>
</div>
<div id="contenedor_img">
Yo contengo una imagen
</div>
```

Por lo que entiendo, canvg no lee la hoja de estilos, así que el SVG debe tener los estilos inline.